# D3 stacked bar chart g and rect not showing

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to D3 and working on a small stacked bar chart from a small JSON data set. The elements are showing up in the DOM, but I cannot get them to actually render on the page. Here is a code pen link:

http://codepen.io/robmweb/pen/epYyLB

and here is the relevant html and JS for posterity's sake:
HTML:

```
<div class="container-dashboard">
  <div class="report-card">
    <div class="card-content" id="report-issues">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
//data
var width = 400;
var height = 250;
var data = 
[
  {
    type: 'Functional',
    total: 8,
    stacks: [1, 1, 2, 4]
  }, {
    type: 'Technical',
    total: 3,
    stacks: [1, 1, 1, 0]
  }, {
    type: 'GUI',
    total: 10,
    stacks: [3, 0, 0, 7]
  }, {
    type: 'Crash',
    total: 8,
    stacks: [8, 0, 0, 0]
  }
];

//add the svg
var svg = d3.select("#report-issues").append("svg")
  .attr({
    class: 'chart',
    width: '400',
    height: '250'
  });

/*
var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data.stacks)])
    .range([0, width]);
*/

var g = svg.selectAll('g').data(data);

g.enter().append('g').attr({
  w: function (d, i) { return width },
  h: function (d, i) { return 30 },
  'transform': function (d, i) {
    return 'translate(0,' + i * 30 + ')';
  },
  'fill': "black"
})

var rect = g.selectAll('rect').data(function(d) {
  return d.stacks;
});

rect.enter().append('rect').attr({
  w: function (d, i) { return d * 3 },
  h: function (d, i) { return 10 },
  x: function (d, i) { return 0 },
  y: function (d, i) { return 0 },
  'fill': "red"
})
```

Any Help would be appreciated, or even links to great tutorials on stacked bar charts that work with similar data (most I can find are matrices).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct attributes for SVG element size are `height` and `width`, not `h` and `w`. There may be other problems with your code, but that change will at least make the bars visible.

```
g.enter().append('g').attr({
  width: function (d, i) { return width },
  height: function (d, i) { return 30 },

//...

rect.enter().append('rect').attr({
  width: function (d, i) { return d * 3 },
  height: function (d, i) { return 10 },
```

Comment: Thank you! It was just me messing up the attribute names.